# I dont understand the behavior of the AutomationProperties class in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, accessibility

I am testing the AutomationProperties class to make the app accessible.
But I don't understand why the HelpText or Name properties that are to help name/describe an element, also occupy space in the visual interface.
I have searched the internet and in the documentation and I have not found anything that explains this.
Can someone explain it?

Empty property:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW85i.png]
Using HelpText:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4UM6.png]
Using Name:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu807.png]

Comment: Is that the latest version of Xamarin updated in the project?

Comment: Checked, VS 2019, Xamarin updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of native accessibility before, even using Xamarin iOS & Xamarin Android for accessibility, and I have never encountered issues like that before.
You are right that the Automation Properties was the Xamarin Forms version of helping to make the app accessible. And this behavior is not appropriate for accessibility. Seems like a bug in Xamarin Forms Automation Properties.

Comment: I have also faced a lot of issues when i did try the automation properties before, so I never rely on it. I would recommend creating an issue in the Xamarin Forms Github repo https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Comment: I find this behavior very strange, at first I thought it was a problem with my code, but when I tried it on a clean project, I worried.
Could it be a new error? It is not normal that neither in the documentation nor in the websites that I have seen talk about this class is there any mention of this problem.

Comment: Another thing, when testing the properties with talk back in android, the assistant reads the properties and also the visual elements (label), this means that it would not be necessary to use these properties unless you need to make a more detailed description?
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Yes you are right. And you did a good job starting fresh. Could you share your code through Github, so we could see if its the same bugs in iOS as well? Digging through the Accessibility work, it seems like most of the work is 8 months old, except for a few changes made 6 days ago and there doesn't seem to be much Label specific work done apart from that. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blame/62dfadabf2bb1f3211deed33b17b0a462c1ba2d9/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Extensions/AccessibilityExtensions.cs
Yes, if the talk back already announces something, then you dont need the properties

Comment: You specially need the properties for images since you dont want to announce the file name ic_back.png for the back button :)